# android-opencv sample crash - tutorial2 Advanced

Tags: android, opencv

I have a problem running tutorial2 (Advanced - Mix java 9+ native
opencv) sample on HTC incredible S.
Other samples work great.
The app terminates immediately with this message: "The application
Tutorial 2 Advanced - 2. Mix Java + Native OpenCV( process
org.opencv.samples.tutorial4) has expired unexpectedly. Please try
again."
Any help or suggestion?

```
02-24 22:27:12.083: I/Process(2212): Sending signal. PID: 2212 SIG: 9
02-24 23:15:34.915: I/Sample::Activity(2296): Instantiated new class
org.opencv.samples.tutorial4.Sample4Mixed
02-24 23:15:34.935: I/Sample::Activity(2296): onCreate
02-24 23:15:34.935: W/dalvikvm(2296): Exception Ljava/lang/
UnsatisfiedLinkError; thrown while initializing Lorg/opencv/samples/
tutorial4/Sample4View;
02-24 23:15:34.935: D/AndroidRuntime(2296): Shutting down VM
02-24 23:15:34.935: W/dalvikvm(2296): threadid=1: thread exiting with
uncaught exception (group=0x4001d5a0)
02-24 23:15:34.945: E/AndroidRuntime(2296): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-24 23:15:34.945: E/AndroidRuntime(2296):
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
02-24 23:15:34.945: E/AndroidRuntime(2296):     at
org.opencv.samples.tutorial4.Sample4Mixed.onCreate(Sample4Mixed.java:
35)
02-24 23:15:34.945: E/AndroidRuntime(2296):     at
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:
1072)
02-24 23:15:34.945: E/AndroidRuntime(2296):     at
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:
1785)
02-24 23:15:34.945: E/AndroidRuntime(2296):     at
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:
1842)
02-24 23:15:34.945: E/AndroidRuntime(2296):     at
android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:132)
02-24 23:15:34.945: E/AndroidRuntime(2296):     at
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1038)
02-24 23:15:34.945: E/AndroidRuntime(2296):     at
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-24 23:15:34.945: E/AndroidRuntime(2296):     at
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
02-24 23:15:34.945: E/AndroidRuntime(2296):     at
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4263)
02-24 23:15:34.945: E/AndroidRuntime(2296):     at
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-24 23:15:34.945: E/AndroidRuntime(2296):     at
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-24 23:15:34.945: E/AndroidRuntime(2296):     at
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit
$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
02-24 23:15:34.945: E/AndroidRuntime(2296):     at
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
02-24 23:15:34.945: E/AndroidRuntime(2296):     at
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-24 23:15:34.945: E/AndroidRuntime(2296): Caused by:
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load mixed_sample:
findLibrary returned null
02-24 23:15:34.945: E/AndroidRuntime(2296):     at
java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:429)
02-24 23:15:34.945: E/AndroidRuntime(2296):     at
java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:554)
02-24 23:15:34.945: E/AndroidRuntime(2296):     at
org.opencv.samples.tutorial4.Sample4View.<clinit>(Sample4View.java:91)
02-24 23:15:34.945: E/AndroidRuntime(2296):     ... 14 more
02-24 23:20:35.008: I/Process(2296): Sending signal. PID: 2296 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 0):

seems like a linking error due to

```
02-24 23:15:34.935: W/dalvikvm(2296): Exception Ljava/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError; thrown while initializing Lorg/opencv/samples/tutorial4/Sample4View;
```

check your project settings for the toolchain for the build settings.

this might bring you more information:
http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/android_binary_package_using_with_NDK.html